# What technology is being used for photofunia.com

Tags: apache-flex, flash, image-processing, image-manipulation

Any idea about what backend technology might be in use for sites like photofunia.com and loonapix.com for image merging to create the effects? is it flash/flex or Open GL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

loonapix is doing server-side image processing to create the effect.  If you look at the cloud  over the ocean one, it looks like they just run a blur (perhaps a guassian blur) and remove the color through desaturation and then colorize it to blue, and then they overlay that on a stock image. This is a total guess, but it feels like they might have done this with Ruby On Rails -- if so, they probably use this: http://rmagick.rubyforge.org/

photofunia is also server-side.  I also noticed that it uses a lot of face recognition to automatically place the face -- for that, they may be using [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/). Otherwise, it's mostly the same thing as loonapix, image processing and compositing on the server-side.

You could use many different image processing libraries to do that ([ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) or [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/)).  I work for a company that makes a .NET imaging SDK that can do it -- [Atalasoft](http://atalasoft.com/products/dotimage).

A few years ago, we posted this sample to show how to use [blurs and noise generators to create random clouds](http://www.atalasoft.com/cs/blogs/31appsin31days/archive/2008/05/09/cloudscape-wallpaper-generator.aspx).  You'd need to do something like that except incorporate a photo into the process.